# Inconsistent accesibility field type

Tags: c#

I'm making a Flappy Bird game, and I'm getting a `Inconsistent Acessibilty Error`.. i maked the entities grammar wrong but it's not giving a fail, this is what i wrote:

```
namespace Flappy_Bird.Screens
{
   public class GameScreen : Screen
   {

       public Texture2D background;
       public Entites.Bird Bird;

       public GameScreen()
       {

       }
       public override void LoadContent()
       {
           background = Statics.CONTENT.Load<Texture2D>("Textures/background");
           Bird = new Entites.Bird();

           base.LoadContent();
       }


       public override void Update()
       {
           Bird.Update();
           base.Update();
       } 


       public override void Draw()
       {
           Statics.SPRITEBATCH.Begin();

           Statics.SPRITEBATCH.Draw(this.background, Vector2.Zero, Color.White);

           Bird.Draw();

           Statics.SPRITEBATCH.End();
           base.Draw();
       }
   }
}




                         `
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect `Screen` is not `public`.

If not that then check the methods you are overriding are also `public`.

Also check `Texture2D` and `Entites.Bird` are `public`.

As a side note, you shouldn't be exposing those variables publicly anyway, use a `property`.  It'll save you hassle further down the line.

Comment: Screen is a Public Abstract class

Comment: Check the methods you're overriding are `public`

Comment: They are public override void but the fail is still there.

Comment: and in screen they are public virtual void.

Comment: Okay so i checked everything and everything is Public and the fail is still there..

Comment: You'll have to post the rest of the code then, I'm just guessing.  The stack trace should tell you what line the error is originating from.